Server Based In Fullstack
I’m working on a project where I have three services running on different ports on my localhost:
Frontend: Port 3000
Backend: Port 2000
Python script (app.py): Port 1500

I want to combine all these ports into a single port so that when I host my application, everything works seamlessly on that single port.
How can I combine these services into a single port?
Are there any free platforms where I can host this combined setup?
I’ve considered using tools like Nginx for reverse proxying but frontend looks blank white screen but backend and app.py works . Any step-by-step guidance or alternate suggestions would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Reverse proxy with nginx or Apache is the most common solution. There are literally hundreds or more step-by-step instructions for that on the Internet so there's really no point in adding one more. Using a general cloud service provider like AWS and Azure is another option.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
